# Cannot read property 'LEENDPOINT' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, logentries

I am integrating LogEntries in my react application.

But right after importing LogEntry `js` file. I am getting console error that:

```
const Logger = require ('./logger.jsx')('your token', {trace: true});
```

Error:

```
le.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LEENDPOINT' of undefined
at new e (le.min.js:5)
at new p (le.min.js:10)
at f (le.min.js:11)
at Object.init (le.min.js:12)
at module.exports (logger.jsx:9)
at Object.defineProperty.value (App.js:10)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9c287bdecc8b4481a87b:19)
at Object.defineProperty.value (AppWrapper.js:2)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9c287bdecc8b4481a87b:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:8)
```

Update:

After debbuging I came to know that window object is undefined in logger file.
This is piece of code which is causing havoc:

```
     if (window.LEENDPOINT) {
        _endpoint = window.LEENDPOINT;
    }
```

Still looking for solution.

Update 2.0:

Here is my Logger.jsx

```
const LogEntries = require ('./le.min.js');

module.exports =  (token, opts={}) => {
if(!token){
    throw new Error ('A valid token is required for all LogEntries library implementations.');
}

opts.token = token;
LogEntries.init(opts);
return LogEntries;
}
```

Comment: window probably could not be null in any browser. Can you shown your `logger.jsx` ?

Comment: @Panther I have updated my question.

Comment: can you replace your `arrow` function under `logger.jsx` to normal function and try it out.

Comment: @Panther previously it was done using `function` keyword I changed to `arrow` function. I thought doing so may remove the error but nothing happens.

Comment: hey, I'm getting this exact error. Have you figured it out?

Comment: @webdevbyjoss are you doing it in react?

Comment: @Dalvik yes, also using the Create React App which builds stuff using Webpack. 
The fact that LE.js client doesn't come as ES6 module makes the whole thing even more complex due to Webpack specifics, like: 

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3247,

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3017

Comment: @webdevbyjoss  I have added my solution as answer. Please check it I hope it may work for you as well. Let me know if it works/not works

Answer (score 1):

Following solution worked for me:

1. Downloaded `le.min.js` from https://docs.logentries.com/docs/javascript
2. Imported `<script src="/assets/scripts/le.min.js"></script>` in my index.html. Make sure you import it before bundle.js
3. Created one file. Logger.js

   `const token =  'token';`

   `const region = 'us';`

   `const trace = true;`

   `/*eslint-disable */`

   `LE.init({ token, region, trace});`

   `export default LE;`

   `/*eslint-enable */`
4. Whenever you want to make log import `import Logger from './Logger';`
5. Log using:  `Logger.error('Log');`